# glDrawElements GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, opengl-3

I try to launch next code, but it gives error with code 1285 on line glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr) (**Application.cpp**).

If I replace preceding line of code with glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3) it draws a triangle, so shader, vertex buffer, vertex array binding works fine. The problem should be in IndexBuffer, but I can't find it.

**Renderer.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <GL/glew.h>

#define ASSERT(x) if (!(x)) __debugbreak();
#define GLCall(x) GLClearError();\
    x;\
    ASSERT(GLLogCall(#x, __FILE__, __LINE__))

void GLClearError();
bool GLLogCall(const char* function, const char* file, int line);
```

**Renderer.cpp**

```
#include "Renderer.h"

#include <iostream>

void GLClearError()
{
    while (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR);
}

bool GLLogCall(const char* function, const char* file, int line)
{
    while (GLenum error = glGetError())
    {
        std::cout << "[OpenGL Error] (" << error << "): " << function <<
            " " << file << ": " << line << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**VertexBuffer.h**

```
#pragma once

class VertexBuffer
{
private:
    unsigned int m_RendererID;
public:
    VertexBuffer(const void* data, unsigned int size);
    ~VertexBuffer();

    void Bind() const;
    void Unbind() const;


};
```

**VertexBuffer.cpp**

```
#include "VertexBuffer.h"

#include "Renderer.h"


VertexBuffer::VertexBuffer(const void* data, unsigned int size)
    
{
    GLCall(glGenBuffers(1, &m_RendererID));
    GLCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_RendererID));
    GLCall(glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW));
}

VertexBuffer::~VertexBuffer()
{
    GLCall(glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_RendererID));
}

void VertexBuffer::Bind() const
{
    GLCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_RendererID));
}

void VertexBuffer::Unbind() const
{
    GLCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0));
}
```

**IndexBuffer.h**

```
#pragma once

class IndexBuffer
{
private:
    unsigned int m_RendererID;
    unsigned int m_Count;
public:
    IndexBuffer(const unsigned int* data, unsigned int count);
    ~IndexBuffer();

    void Bind() const;
    void Unbind() const;

    inline unsigned int GetCount() const { return m_Count; }

};
```

**IndexBuffer.cpp**

```
#include "IndexBuffer.h"

#include "Renderer.h"

IndexBuffer::IndexBuffer(const unsigned int* data, unsigned int count)
    : m_Count(count)
{
    ASSERT(sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(GLuint));

    GLCall(glGenBuffers(1, &m_RendererID));
    GLCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_RendererID));
    GLCall(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, count * sizeof(unsigned int), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

IndexBuffer::~IndexBuffer()
{
    GLCall(glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_RendererID));
}

void IndexBuffer::Bind() const
{
    GLCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_RendererID));
}

void IndexBuffer::Unbind() const
{
    GLCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0));
}
```

**Application.cpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>



#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include "Renderer.h"

#include "VertexBuffer.h"
#include "IndexBuffer.h"


struct ShaderProgramSource
{
    std::string VertexSource;
    std::string FragmentSource;
};

static ShaderProgramSource ParseShader(const std::string& filepath)
{
    std::fstream stream(filepath);

    enum class ShaderType
    {
        NONE = -1, VERTEX = 0, FRAGMENT = 1
    };

    std::string line;
    std::stringstream ss[2];
    ShaderType type = ShaderType::NONE;

    while (getline(stream, line))
    {
        if (line.find("#shader") != std::string::npos) 
        {
            if (line.find("vertex") != std::string::npos)
            {
                type = ShaderType::VERTEX;
            }
            else if (line.find("fragment") != std::string::npos)
            {
                type = ShaderType::FRAGMENT;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            ss[(int)type] << line << '\n';
        }
    }

    return { ss[0].str(), ss[1].str() };

}

static unsigned int CompileShader(unsigned int type, const std::string& source)
{
    GLCall(unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type));
    const char* src = source.c_str();

    GLCall(glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr));
    GLCall(glCompileShader(id));

    int result;
    GLCall(glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result));

    if (result == GL_FALSE) 
    {
        int length;
        GLCall(glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length));

        char* message = (char*)alloca(length * sizeof(char));

        GLCall(glGetShaderInfoLog(id, length, &length, message));
        std::cout << "Failed to compile " << (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex" : "fragment") << " shader!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
    
        GLCall(glDeleteShader(id));
        return 0;
    }

    return id;
}

static unsigned int CreateProgram(const std::string& vertexShader, const std::string& fragmentShader)
{
    GLCall(unsigned int program = glCreateProgram());
    unsigned int vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    unsigned int fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);

    GLCall(glAttachShader(program, vs));
    GLCall(glAttachShader(program, fs));
    GLCall(glLinkProgram(program));
    GLCall(glValidateProgram(program));

    GLCall(glDeleteShader(vs));
    GLCall(glDeleteShader(fs));

    return program;
}


int main()
{

    GLFWwindow* window;

    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 400, "Hello world", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }


    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "Error while GLEW init!" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

    {

        float positions[] = {
            -0.5f, -0.5f,  // 0
             0.5f, -0.5f,  // 1
             0.5f,  0.5f,  // 2
            -0.5f,  0.5f  // 3
        };

        unsigned int indices[] = {
            0, 1, 2,
            2, 3, 0
        };

        unsigned int vao;
        GLCall(glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao));
        GLCall(glBindVertexArray(vao));

        VertexBuffer vb(positions, 4 * 2 * sizeof(float));

        GLCall(glEnableVertexAttribArray(0));
        GLCall(glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0));

        IndexBuffer ib(indices, 6);

        ShaderProgramSource source = ParseShader("res/shaders/Basic.shader");
        unsigned int program = CreateProgram(source.VertexSource, source.FragmentSource);
        GLCall(glUseProgram(program));

        GLCall(int location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "u_Color"));
        ASSERT(location != -1);
        GLCall(glUniform4f(location, 0.8f, 0.3f, 0.8f, 1.0f));

        GLCall(glBindVertexArray(0));
        GLCall(glUseProgram(0));
        vb.Unbind();
        ib.Unbind();

        float r = 0;
        float increment = 0.05f;

        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
        {
            GLCall(glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT));
            glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);

            GLCall(glUseProgram(program));
            GLCall(glUniform4f(location, r, 0.3f, 0.8f, 1.0f));

            GLCall(glBindVertexArray(vao));
            ib.Bind();
            
        //  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
            GLCall(glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr));

            if (r > 1.0f)
            {
                increment = -0.05f;
            }
            else if (r < 0.0f)
            {
                increment = 0.05f;
            }

            r += increment;

    
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);


            glfwPollEvents();

        }

        GLCall(glDeleteProgram(program));

    }

    glfwTerminate();
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Basic.shader**

```
#shader vertex
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
}

#shader fragment
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

uniform vec4 u_Color;

void main()
{
    color = u_Color;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem but your OpenGL wrapper classes all violate the rule of five. This is almost certainly going to cause you issues down the road. If you want to free OpenGL ressources in your destructors you should peroperly handle copy/move semantics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not look right. Missing a glBufferData?

```
GLCall(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, count * sizeof(unsigned int), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not careful :)